# I'm having trouble outputing the user's amount of guesses in a Hangman game

Tags: java, loops

This is basically just a hangman project for my class and I'm not allowed to use arrays. The word is hidden with dashes to the user.The user has to pick a letter and the number of spaces they would like to check. The user has a certain amount of guess depending on the difficulty they choose. If the letter they guessed is in at least one of the spaces they chose then the user loses no guesses, if the letter they guessed is in none of the spaces they chose then the user loses a guess.

for example the output should look like

**The secret word is: loops**

**The word is: -----**

**Please enter the letter you want to guess**

*k*

**Please enter the spaces you want to check (separated by spaces)**

*0 1 2 3*

**Your letter was not found in spaces you provided**

**Guesses Remaining: 14**

But it currently looks like this

**The secret word is: loops**

**The word is: -----**

**Please enter the letter you want to guess**

*k*

**Please enter the spaces you want to check (separated by spaces)**

*0 1 2 3*

**Your letter was not found in spaces you provided**

**Guesses Remaining: 14**

**Your letter was not found in spaces you provided**

**Guesses Remaining: 13**

**Your letter was not found in spaces you provided**

**Guesses Remaining: 12**

**Your letter was not found in spaces you provided**

**Guesses Remaining: 11**

Here is what I have so far

```
  package e;

  import java.util.Scanner;

public class HangmanBeta{
private static final boolean testingMode = true;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    keyboard.useDelimiter("\\n"); 
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter your difficulty: Easy (e), Intermediate (i), or Hard (h)");
        String diff = keyboard.next();
        int amountOfSpaces = 0;
        String response = "";
        String guess = "";
        String newGuess = "";
        String letterInput = "";

        int count = 0;
        String newWord = "loops";//RandomWord.newWord();

        int guesses = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < newWord.length(); i++) {
            guess = newWord.replaceAll("[^#]", "-");
        }
        if ((diff.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) || (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("i")) || (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))) {
            if (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))
            {
                guesses = 15;
            }
            if(diff.equalsIgnoreCase("i"))
            {
                guesses = 12;
            }
            if(diff.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))
            {
                guesses = 15;
            }
            if (testingMode == true)
            {
                System.out.println("The secret word is:" + " " + newWord);
            }
            System.out.println("The word is:" + " " + guess);

            while(!newWord.equalsIgnoreCase(guess))
                innerloop:
                { while(true)
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter the letter you want to guess");
                    letterInput = keyboard.next();
                    letterInput = Character.toString(letterInput.charAt(0));

                    if(!Character.isLetter(letterInput.charAt(0)))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Your input is not valid, try again");
                        break;
                    }
                    if(letterInput.equalsIgnoreCase("solve"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Please solve the answer:");
                        String userSolve = keyboard.next();
                        if (!userSolve.equalsIgnoreCase(newWord))
                        {
                            System.out.println("That is not the secret word");
                            guesses = guesses - 1;
                            System.out.println("Guesses remaining: " + guesses);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("You win!");
                            System.out.println("You have guessed the word! Congratulations");
                            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Yes(y) or No (n)");
                            response = keyboard.next();
                            if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
                            {
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Please enter the spaces you want to check (separated by spaces)");
                    String spaces = keyboard.next();
                    amountOfSpaces = spaces.length();
                    if (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))
                    {
                        if(amountOfSpaces != 7)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Your input is not valid, try again");
                            break innerloop;
                        }

                    }
                    if (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("i"))
                    {
                        if(amountOfSpaces != 5)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Your input is not valid, try again");   
                            break innerloop;
                        }
                    }

                    if (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))
                    {
                        if(amountOfSpaces != 3)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Your input is not valid, try again");
                            break innerloop;
                        }
                    }



                    for ( String a : spaces.split("\\s"))
                    {



                        int x = Integer.valueOf(a);
                        if (x > guess.length())
                        {
                            System.out.println("Your input is not valid, try again");
                            break innerloop;
                        }

                        if (Character.toLowerCase(newWord.charAt(x)) == letterInput.charAt(0)) 
                        {
                            //System.out.println("Guess is correct for position " + x);
                            guess = guess.substring(0, x) + letterInput + guess.substring(x + 1, guess.length());

                        }
                        if (Character.toLowerCase(newWord.charAt(x)) != letterInput.charAt(0))
                        {


                            guesses= guesses - 1;
                            System.out.println("Your letter was not found in spaces you provided");
                            System.out.println("Guesses Remaining: " + guesses);

                        }

                        if (guesses == 0)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You have failed to guess the word....:(");
                            System.out.print("Would you like to play again? Yes(y) or No(n)");
                            response = keyboard.next();
                            if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
                            {
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }   
                    } 
                }

                if (newWord.equalsIgnoreCase(guess))
                {
                    System.out.println("You win!");
                    System.out.println("You have guessed the word! Congratulations");
                    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Yes(y) or No (n)");
                    response = keyboard.next();
                    if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
                    {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                }
                }   
            System.out.println("Your Guess is in the word");
        }
        if(guesses == guesses - 1)
        {



            //System.out.print(spaces.split("\\s").length);
            //System.out.println("Your Guess is in the word");
            //System.out.println();
            //System.out.println("Updated word " + guess);
            //System.out.println("Guesses Remaining: " + guesses);
        }
    }
} 






}
```

In the example I used the difficulty was set to easy.

Comment: You really want to read about single layer of abstraction. Your approach to pus all content into a single method renders your code almost unreadable.

Comment: How exactly should I make this more readable then? My class has not learned anything about creating new methods yet. I've only started coding 2 months ago and I'm still learning english so maybe I'm reading your comment wrong?

Comment: Though luck then. Maybe you should ask your teacher then to tell you about methods then. The ability to reasonably structure your code by putting it into smaller methods is an essential part of programming ; and one should start practicing that as soon as possible. The point is that your brain can easily understand a few lines of code. But as soon as it has to deal with more than that, one gets lost. That is why you now need other people to explain to you what YOUR code is doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug here:

```
                      if (Character.toLowerCase(newWord.charAt(x)) != letterInput.charAt(0))
                    {


                        guesses= guesses - 1;
                        System.out.println("Your letter was not found in spaces you provided");
                        System.out.println("Guesses Remaining: " + guesses);

                    }
```

You cannot print the message directly because you need to make sure all spaces are not matched. This should be work:

```
public class HangmanBeta {
private static final boolean testingMode = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    keyboard.useDelimiter("\\n");
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter your difficulty: Easy (e), Intermediate (i), or Hard (h)");
        String diff = keyboard.next();
        int amountOfSpaces = 0;
        String response = "";
        String guess = "";
        String newGuess = "";
        String letterInput = "";

        int count = 0;
        String newWord = "loops";//RandomWord.newWord();

        int guesses = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < newWord.length(); i++) {
            guess = newWord.replaceAll("[^#]", "-");
        }
        if ((diff.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) || (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("i")) || (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))) {
            if (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {
                guesses = 15;
            }
            if (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("i")) {
                guesses = 12;
            }
            if (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("h")) {
                guesses = 15;
            }
            if (testingMode == true) {
                System.out.println("The secret word is:" + " " + newWord);
            }
            System.out.println("The word is:" + " " + guess);

            while (!newWord.equalsIgnoreCase(guess))
                innerloop:
                        {
                            while (true) {
                                System.out.println("Please enter the letter you want to guess");
                                letterInput = keyboard.next();
                                letterInput = Character.toString(letterInput.charAt(0));

                                if (!Character.isLetter(letterInput.charAt(0))) {
                                    System.out.println("Your input is not valid, try again");
                                    break;
                                }
                                if (letterInput.equalsIgnoreCase("solve")) {
                                    System.out.println("Please solve the answer:");
                                    String userSolve = keyboard.next();
                                    if (!userSolve.equalsIgnoreCase(newWord)) {
                                        System.out.println("That is not the secret word");
                                        guesses = guesses - 1;
                                        System.out.println("Guesses remaining: " + guesses);
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("You win!");
                                        System.out.println("You have guessed the word! Congratulations");
                                        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Yes(y) or No (n)");
                                        response = keyboard.next();
                                        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                                            System.exit(0);
                                        }
                                        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                                            continue;
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                                System.out.println("Please enter the spaces you want to check (separated by spaces)");
                                String spaces = keyboard.next();
                                amountOfSpaces = spaces.length();
                                if (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {
                                    if (amountOfSpaces != 7) {
                                        System.out.println("Your input is not valid, try again");
                                        break innerloop;
                                    }

                                }
                                if (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("i")) {
                                    if (amountOfSpaces != 5) {
                                        System.out.println("Your input is not valid, try again");
                                        break innerloop;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("h")) {
                                    if (amountOfSpaces != 3) {
                                        System.out.println("Your input is not valid, try again");
                                        break innerloop;
                                    }
                                }

                                int numSpacesLeft = spaces.split("\\s").length;

                                for (String a : spaces.split("\\s")) {


                                    int x = Integer.valueOf(a);
                                    if (x > guess.length()) {
                                        System.out.println("Your input is not valid, try again");
                                        break innerloop;
                                    }

                                    if (Character.toLowerCase(newWord.charAt(x)) == letterInput.charAt(0)) {
                                        //System.out.println("Guess is correct for position " + x);
                                        guess = guess.substring(0, x) + letterInput + guess.substring(x + 1, guess.length());

                                    }

                                    numSpacesLeft--;

                                    if (Character.toLowerCase(newWord.charAt(x)) != letterInput.charAt(0)) {

                                        if (numSpacesLeft == 0) {
                                            guesses = guesses - 1;
                                            System.out.println("Your letter was not found in spaces you provided");
                                            System.out.println("Guesses Remaining: " + guesses);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if (guesses == 0) {
                                        System.out.println("You have failed to guess the word....:(");
                                        System.out.print("Would you like to play again? Yes(y) or No(n)");
                                        response = keyboard.next();
                                        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                                            System.exit(0);
                                        }
                                        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            if (newWord.equalsIgnoreCase(guess)) {
                                System.out.println("You win!");
                                System.out.println("You have guessed the word! Congratulations");
                                System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Yes(y) or No (n)");
                                response = keyboard.next();
                                if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }
                                if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                                    continue;
                                }

                            }
                        }
            System.out.println("Your Guess is in the word");
        }
        if (guesses == guesses - 1) {


            //System.out.print(spaces.split("\\s").length);
            //System.out.println("Your Guess is in the word");
            //System.out.println();
            //System.out.println("Updated word " + guess);
            //System.out.println("Guesses Remaining: " + guesses);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Hop this could help you!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help its been taking me days to fix this!

Comment: I'm happy it could help you :)